# require() in node.js is not working and returns error?

Tags: node.js, module, require

I have looked through stackoverflow and read about require. However I cannot understand why my require function does not run.

app.js code:

```js
var http = require('http');
var express = require("express");
var app = express();


//Twitter Search -------------------
app.get("/tweet, function(req,res){
        
    var twiter = require('twiter.js');
});


app.listen(3000);
```

twitter.js code:

```js
console.log("twitter.js ran");
```

Comment: Returns: Error: Cannot find module 'twiter.js' at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15).. etc

Comment: If `twiter.js` is a file, you need to require with a relative path. `require('./twiter')`

Comment: where is twitter.js located..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure both `app.js` and `twitter.js` in same directory
And add `./` before it. Just use following

`var twitter = require('./twitter');` // `.js` extension is not necessary

Also as alexey mentioned. `twiter` is not same as `twitter` :)
Take care of your typos. (I think I'm too lazy to read it carefully)

app.js

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require("express");
var app = express();


//Twitter Search -------------------
app.get("/tweet", function (req, res) {

    var twitter = require('./twitter');
    twitter.log();
});


app.listen(3000);
```

twitter.js should be exposed using module.exports

```
var twitter = {
    log: function () {
        console.log('twitter is loaded');
    }
};
module.exports = twitter;
```

This should now print "twitter is loaded" in your console, when you visit `localhost:3000/tweet`

Comment: Also should mention to check typos. `twiter` is not the same as `twitter`

Comment: Thank you for this, both of you were correct I noticed the typo after reading the initial response. Thanks J